# Cannot fit images inside grid card

Tags: html, css, css-grid

This should be trivial, but I can not get images to fit inside a card inside a responsive grid:
Here is the CSS:

```
body {
  background-color: gery;
}

.cards {
  margin: 0 auto;
  max-width: 1000px;
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(auto-fill, minmax(225px, 1fr));
  grid-auto-rows: auto;
  gap: 20px;
   padding-top: 30px;
 
}

.card {
  background-color: #fff;
  line-height: 1.5;
  font-size: 1.1em;
  padding: 15px;
  background: #fafafa;
}

.card__image {
    width: 100% !important;
    height: 150px;
    object-fit: cover;
    display: block;
}
```

And the HTML

```
<div class="cards">
        <div class="card"> 
                    <a href="#">                       
                        <img class="card__image" loading="lazy" src="https://fakeimg.pl/200x100/ff0000/">                     
                    </a>
                <strong><a href="/#"> loerm ipsum</a></strong>               
        </div>
        <div class="card">                
                    <a href="#">                       
                        <img class="card__image" loading="lazy" src="https://fakeimg.pl/200x100/ff0000/">                     
                    </a>
                <strong><a href="/#">bla blaxum</a></strong>   
        </div>
</div>
```

codepen:

https://codepen.io/bcodus/pen/RwpGYaQ

Notice that there is a margin around img which should not be there.

Appreciate your help to fix this.

Comment: N.B. it's not a margin around img... is the padding of the .card div (padding:15px )

Comment: Right. Thanks for the tip. It solved the issue.

Comment: @Sfili_81 please give your answer in the answer section not in a comment.

Comment: it's not an answer it's a comment